# Programmatically detect type of connection to mounted volume

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am copying files between local and mounted filesystems where the mounted systems can be USB, FireWire, AFP, or remote servers.  I need to identify what sort of connection to the computer the mounted volume is using.  I can use the [statfs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/statfs.2.html) system call to identify what sort of filesystem that is mounted, but I am unable to figure out how to identify the type of connection (FireWire, Wifi, eth, USB...). My code to identify the  filesystem is:

```
-(void) getVolumeInfo:(NSURL *) myurl
{
    struct statfs buf;
    statfs([myurl.path UTF8String], &buf);
    NSLog(@"Filesystem type: %s mounted filesystem: %s mounted as:  %s",buf.f_fstypename,buf.f_mntfromname,buf.f_mntonname);
}
```

Which gives the following output for my laptop harddrive and my NAS server.

```
Filesystem type: hfs mounted filesystem: /dev/disk0s2 mounted as: /
Filesystem type: afpfs mounted filesystem: //Trond%20Kristiansen@HerlighetNASserver._afpovertcp._tcp.local/home mounted as: /Volumes/home
```

My questions are: 1) Does anyone know how I can identify through code how for example the NAS server is connected (wifi or network cable) 2) Is there anyway I can detect the connection speed?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show me how to mounted filesystems? Thanks

Comment: could you please add 2 things to the question: 1) what is the "myurl" input and how it looks like 2) how do you obtain it -- meaning, where and how do you enlist mounted volumes... The scenario is too vague

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To determine the type of connection (currently active interface), you may be able to use the [System Configuration Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Networking/Reference/SysConfig/_index.html). Some of the functions in [SCNetworkConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Networking/Reference/SCNetworkConfiguration/Reference/reference.html) may provide information on the currently active interface...It appears that there are some throughput/statistics functions defined in the [SCNetworkConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Networking/Reference/SCNetworkConfiguration/Reference/reference.html), but they appear to apply to PPP connection types.

You may also find some helpful methods in [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/getFileSystemInfoForPath%3aisRemovable%3aisWritable%3aisUnmountable%3adescription%3atype%3a), but it seems like you may have the filesystem information covered.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/NSWorkspace.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
    BOOL isRemovable, isWritable, isUnmountable;
    NSString *description, *type;

    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] getFileSystemInfoForPath:@"/Volumes/Users"
                                                        isRemovable:&isRemovable
                                                         isWritable:&isWritable
                                                      isUnmountable:&isUnmountable
                                                        description:&description
                                                               type:&type];

    NSLog(@"Filesystem description:%@ type:%@ removable:%d writable:%d unmountable:%d", description, type, isRemovable, isWritable, isUnmountable);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that on newer systems this may fail (and return NO/nil on the inout parameters) for paths the sandbox won't let you access without prompting the user first. If you can, use a known-accessible path like the Library.

Comment: The NSWorkspace is really cute and helpful for many uses, and I'll sure employ it for these - what's better than a clear one-liner with so many answers? However, if I NEED a little more "file-system-information" on a "Mount point" like, is it a USB device? what is its Serial number? Who is its Maker? Information of the kind you see in "Disk Utility". do you know where to get these?

Comment: It also seems that the API is "lying" too... Here is the output of your string for one volume on my external OWC hard drive, connected via usb-C/thunderbolt: "MountPoint: /Volumes/MediaStore Filesystem description:apfs type:apfs removable:0 writable:1 unmountable:0" whereas the volume is BOTH unmountable, and removable??? what gives?